# C++ find file on LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c++, c, stat

In C/C++ Is there an existing way to check to see if a particular file is on a particular path?  I imagine syntax that might look like stat() but with additional parms for filename and path.

```
pathstat( struct stat stResult, const char* filename, const char* path );
```

Comment: There might be a way in one of the many, many function libraries available for C++. Since the range of these libraries is vast, platform dependent, and very much depending on your requirements, there is no way to answer your question. I might tell you how to do it in Boost, and you tell me there's a company policy against it. I might tell you how to do it in Qt, and you tell me you're doing GTK. That's the beauty and bane of C++: The "standard" itself does very little, but your choices in available third-party code are next to infinite.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is a common place holder for "C or C++" used by non-programmers who don't know what || means and picked up by programmers because it's easier to type.

Comment: @WesMiller: I see. So, which one are you _actually_ using? Or are you actually looking for a POSIX function?

Comment: +1 @DevSolar.  Well reasoned and stated.  I can of course, write my own.  I just wanted to avoid duplication of effort.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

using `access()` function with `F_OK` flag will check if your file exist. but before that you have to prepare the file path (from `filename` and `path` variables ) before pass the file path as input argument in the function `access()`.

In this answer I assume that you use linux as platform

```
void pathstat( struct stat stResult, const char* filename, const char* path )
    char *file;
    int path_len;

    if (!filename) {
        // set error in the stResult
        return;
    }

    path_len = path ? strlen(path) : 0;

    file = malloc((strlen(filename) + path_len + 2) * sizeof(char));
    // PREPARE THE FILE PATH
    if (path && path[0] && path[path_len-1]=='/')
        sprintf(file,"%s%s",path,filename);
    else if (path && path[0])
        sprintf(file,"%s/%s",path,filename);
    else
        file = strcpy(file,filename);

    //NOW CHECK IF THE FILE PATH EXIST WITH ACCESS
    if (access(file, F_OK) != -1) {
        //file exist
    } else {
        // file does not exxit
    }
    free(file);
}
```

Comment: Care to provide some explanation with your answer?

Comment: I know it's just example code, but I hate to see S.O. answers that contain potential buffer overflow security problems because people will often copy&paste&use this code as is. More importantly, `const char* path` is expected to be a `:`-separated path, so you have to parse it into its components, not just concatenate `filename` to it. Finally, it is almost never correct to use the `access()` system call. Its function is to test permissions using the real credentials in place of the effective credentials, which is almost never what you want. Use `stat` instead, which the OP requires anyway.

Comment: for the buffer over flow. you are right I have to replace it with malloc instead

Comment: for the `"path is expected to be a :-separated path"`: I never seen a `:` as separator for path of linux or windows. this wierd the path separoter I knwo for both platforms are `/` and `\`

Comment: for using `access` to check if file exist. Please refer to the man page of access. in the man they say: `"or the existence test, F_OK."`  http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/access/

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL look in the title of the question. This is about `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which, like `$PATH`, it `:`-separated. As for `access`, it doesn't matter what mode (`F_OK` or other) you pass, it still substitutes the real credentials for the effective ones, which is not what you want. `stat` works just as well as an existence test, does not have the unwanted credential substitution "feature", and is clearly what the OP asked: `struct stat` is mentioned in the question.